# How to uninstall Stellarium?

Tags: uninstall

I installed *Stellarium* on my *eeePC901* like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stellarium/stellarium-releases

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install stellarium
```

When I try to launch the program I get an error message going like this:

> No OpenGL 2 found on this system. Please upgrade hardware or use MESA
>   or an older version.

I want to unistall *Stellarium* and then install an older version.

My question is: How do I uninstall stellarium?

Comment: I reccomend you select an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

```
 sudo apt-get remove stellarium
```

This will remove the `stellarium` package.

Comment: is removing the package the same as removing the program itself from the computer? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: The given command will remove the stellaruim program from your computer

Comment: I've done so, however the stellarium's folder $HOME/.stellarium is still there and config.ini in this folder is still available. Is there a way to remove all of stellarium?

Comment: run the command

sudo apt-get autoremove 

this will removes certain types of packages. It removes packages that depend on other packages. Even you can select the folder that remains and shift delete the same.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Ubuntu Software Center`.Search for `Stellarium`.Click the option `Unistall`.

Answer (score 1):

Fireup Synaptic Package Manager, select Stellarium and Mark for complete removal ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ppa-purge` to remove whatever was installed from that PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:stellarium/stellarium-releases
```

So if any other packages were installed out of the PPA, they are also removed

See also:

- [`ppa-purge` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ppa-purge.1.html)